# Impose a Memory Limit on the CLR

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm trying to test the error handling of my code under limited memory situations.

I'm also keen to see how the performance of my code is affected in low memory situations where perhaps the GC has to run more often.

Is there a way of running a .Net applicataion (or NUnit test-suite) with limited memory? I know with Java you can limit the amount of memory the JVM has access to - is there something similar in .Net?

Comment: I'm not writing an answer because this isn't something I've had to do before, but my first instinct would be to spin up a VM and limit the amount of memory it has; that way you are accounting for things such as OS and other applications that need to be running as well as your own.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an option in the CLR.  Memory is managed *very* differently, there are at least 10 distinct heaps in a .NET process.  A .NET program can use the entire virtual memory space available in a Windows process without restrictions.

The simplest approach is to just allocate the memory when your program starts.  You have to be a bit careful, you cannot swallow too much in one gulp, the address space is *fragmented* due to it containing a mix of code and data at different addresses.  Memory is allocated from the holes in between.  To put a serious dent into the available address space, you have to allocate at least a gigabyte and that's not possible with a single allocation.

So just use a loop to allocate smaller chunks, say one megabyte at a time:

```
    private static List<byte[]> Gobble = new List<byte[]>();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int megabyte = 0; megabyte < 1024; megabyte++) 
           Gobble.Add(new byte[1024 * 1024]);
        // etc..
    }
```

Note that this is *very* fast, the allocated address space is just reserved and doesn't occupy any RAM.

Comment: This probably works but will make the entire machine unusable. Paging frenzy, other processes crashing, ... Chrome for example crashes immediately once you exhaust the commit limit.

Comment: @usr - you didn't pay attention to the last paragraph.  Just try this.

Comment: This still discounts from the Windows commit charge limit because Windows promises your process this amount of memory. You are still exhausting an OS level resource. Windows never over-commits memory.

Comment: Nothing much to fear from the paging file.  Nevertheless, this **was** the OP's intention.  He wants to see what happens when his program uses too much memory.  Using a lot of memory is an excellent test of that.  If he want it *slow* as well then simply fill the array.

Comment: Yeah, your answer works. Just wanted to point out that disadvantage. I consider it to be a severe disadvantage to potentially destabilize the workstation/server.

Comment: @usr You've completely missed the point. This is for testing purposes - maybe if Chrome developers had performed this test, it wouldn't crash in constrained memory scenarios. You could write a program that only needs 1MB ram to run, and it could still be valuable information to know how your program behaves should another program hog up a large amount of system resources. If Windows or other applications are destabilized, it indicates you were *successful* in configuring this test.

Comment: @280Z28 what would you say if your test runner or Visual Studio crashed? Your SVN tool? ... Also think of the paging frenzy imposed on all running processes. Again, this works but a better solution is available (see my answer). And yes, Chrome devs should have tested for this ... using jobs which would have been easy to do and clean.

Comment: @usr - There is no "paging frenzy".  Nothing is getting paged.  That doesn't happen until the array elements are actually accessed in code.  Which doesn't happen.  You really should try this for yourself.

Comment: No paging frenzy, true. But the problem that no other process in the system can allocate memory still stands. I just tested that with the code you provided. When I ran it the DWM exited immediately and warnings popped up. I quickly killed the process because I care about the programs I have running right now. Very dangerous indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can enlist your process into a Windows Job Object. You can set memory (and other) limits for the job. This is the cleanest and the only sane way to limit the amount of memory that your process can use.

Comment: No, but this is not .NET specific. Use PInvoke to call the necessary Win32 APIs. The signatures are probably already available on the web.